# Trying to get property 'menu_display_categories' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I'm having issues with this... I'm trying to install "downGrade - Single Vendor Digital Products Marketplace
"
https://codecanyon.net/item/downgrade-single-vendor-digital-products-marketplace/28803672?gclid=Cj0KCQjw2MWVBhCQARIsAIjbwoOi08ajt47xsPKUsGZ7V7mr7KD5W_CwaQS-BfF1tbP1OE0-LpNdR6caAmCbEALw_wcB

I'm getting this error code and I'd like to receive your help, thank you.

[image: image with error]

[image: image with code]

```
    $admin = Members::adminData();

    View::share('admin', $admin);



    $allsettings = Settings::allSettings();

    View::share('allsettings', $allsettings);



    $allcountry = Settings::allCountry();

    View::share('allcountry', $allcountry);



    $country['country'] = Settings::allCountry();

    View::share('country', $country);



    $demo_mode = 'off'; // on

    View::share('demo_mode', $demo_mode);



    $main_menu['category'] = Category::mainmenuCategoryData($allsettings->menu_display_categories,$allsettings->menu_categories_order);

    View::share('main_menu', $main_menu);





    $footer_menu['category'] = Category::mainmenuCategoryData($allsettings->footer_menu_display_categories,$allsettings->footer_menu_categories_order);

    View::share('footer_menu', $footer_menu);



    $footerpages['pages'] = Pages::footermenuData();

    View::share('footerpages', $footerpages);





    $languages['view'] = Languages::allLanguage();

    View::share('languages', $languages);



    if(!empty(Cookie::get('translate')))

    {
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `$allsettings` is not an `object`. Based on the code it is most likely `null`. Try doing a `dd($allsettings);` to see what the actual value is. You might also want to consider creating a support request with the developer you purchased the code from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you getting the error is that the `$allsetting` is null.

```
$main_menu['category'] = Category::mainmenuCategoryData($allsettings->menu_display_categories,$allsettings->menu_categories_order);
```

The `$allsettings` gets the value from the setting table from the database where you can easily see the value `menu_display_categories` is nulled.

```
  //Nulled here  ---> $allsettings->menu_display_categories
```

[image]

**Solution: Enter the values in all columns inside the setting table.**